# <a> tag link from asset folder html file

Tags: android

In webview html file which is in asset folder, i use just username of facebook id. here is in MainActivity included fixed URL for facebook app and browser. the problem is that when i click someone's profile link Showing ::::URL like this

```
    https://www.facebook.com/file///{FBuserID}
    fb://profile/file///{FBuserID}
```

But I need like this....

```
https://www.facebook.com/{FBuserID}
fb://profile/{FBuserID}
```

Its from MainActivity.java (here is in last ***ELSE*** included two fixed url

```
   webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),(getString(R.string.call_toast)),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                return true;

            } else if (url.startsWith("mailto:")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),(getString(R.string.email_toast)),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                return true;
            }  else {
                if (isAppInstalled(liContext, "com.facebook.orca") || isAppInstalled(liContext, "com.facebook.katana")
                        || isAppInstalled(liContext, "com.example.facebook") || isAppInstalled(liContext, "com.facebook.android")) {
                        view.getContext().startActivity(
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://profile/"+url)));
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),(getString(R.string.facebook_view)),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                        view.getContext().startActivity(
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/"+url)));
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),(getString(R.string.not_fb)),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                return true;
            }

        }


    });
```

Comment: Looks like your `url` contains two extra forward slashes at the very beginning. Therefore, simply trim those unwanted characters out.

Comment: at the very beginning like (fb:// & https://) these are the part of fixed url. if i remove these then URL not to be specified.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/"+url....here URL = last part of fixed url <a href="/../100015720708849"><a/>

Comment: `new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://profile/"+url)));` I said "at the very beginning of **url**" meaning that the string you have in the variable `url` begins with "//", i.e.: "//the_real_url". Hope it's clear now

Comment: i run  code with accepting your idea. but (file:/// ) remain. not removed. why ?

Comment: real url setting on HTML file that is in asset folder. <a href="/../100015720708849"><a/>

Comment: `file:///` is correct for **files**, such as those in the `assets` folder. you asked in the case of facebook

Comment: when i click someone's profile link .......its showing  like that............https://www.facebook.com/file///5096759867895

Comment: Are you storing the profiles on the disk? why is there `file///` in between?!